# How to extract missing Questions with SQL

Tags: sql

**Table 1:**

```
id | question_descr
===================
1  | blabla
2  | lorem
3  | ipsum
4  | dante
5  | alighieri
```

**Table 2**

```
id | user_name | question_id
============================
1  | test_user | 2
2  | test_user | 4
3  | test_user | 5
```

There are some missing, like: 1,3

**Result Expected:**

```
user_name | question_id
============================
test_user | 1
test_user | 3
```

Comment: Look at sql joins for this.

Comment: How do you know which test_user to choose? I assume they have different user names... You could adjust the sample data to make it more like real-case data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a calendar table left anti-join approach here:

```sql
SELECT t2.user_name, t1.id AS question_id
FROM Table1 t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_name FROM Table2) t2
LEFT JOIN Table2 t
    ON t.question_id = t1.id AND
       t.user_name = t2.user_name
WHERE t.id IS NULL
ORDER BY t2.user_name, t1.id;
```